# Why does torchvision.utils.make_grid() return copies of the wanted grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

In the below coding example I can not understand why the output tensor , `grid` has a shape of
`3,28,280`. I understand why its `28` in height and `280` in width, but not the 3. It seems from running `plt.imshow()` on all 3 `28x280` arrays along axis 0 that they are identical copies since printing any 1 of these gives me the image I want.
Also I do not understand why I can pass `grid` as an argument to `plt.imshow()` given that it is supposed to take in a 2D array, not a 3D one as `grid` clearly is.

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

train_set = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root = './pytorch_obj_classifier/data/FashionMNIST',
    train = True,
    download = True,
    transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
)
sample = next(iter(train_loader))
image,label = sample
print(image.shape)

grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(image,padding=0, nrow=10)
print(grid.shape)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
grid = np.transpose(grid,(1,2,0))
grid1 = grid[:,:,0]
grid2 = grid[:,:,1]
grid3 = grid[:,:,2]
plt.imshow(grid1,cmap = 'gray')
plt.imshow(grid2,cmap = 'gray')
plt.imshow(grid3,cmap = 'gray')
plt.imshow(grid,cmap = 'gray')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset consists of grascale images. If you look at the [implementation detail](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/6315358dd06e3a2bcbe9c1e8cdaa10898ac2b308/torchvision/utils.py#L59) of [`torchvision.utils.make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/utils.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid), single-channel images get their channel copied three times:

```
if tensor.dim() == 4 and tensor.size(1) == 1:  # single-channel images
    tensor = torch.cat((tensor, tensor, tensor), 1)
```

As for [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) it can take 2D, 3D or 4D inputs:

> The image data. Supported array shapes are:
>
> - (M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a colormap.
> - (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).
> - (M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e. including transparency.

Generally speaking, we wouldn't refer to dimensions but rather describe tensors by their shape (the size on each of their axes). In PyTorch, images always have three axes, and have a shape that follows: `(channel, height, width)`. Even for single-channel images: considering it as a 3D tensor `(1, height, width)` instead of a 2D tensor `(height, width)`. This is to be consistant with cases where you have more than one channel, which is *very often* (*cf*. convolution neural networks).

Comment: Thanks Ill start checking the source code more often !